# Interpolating Dataframe's column with non-null values with a specific period

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this,

[Dataframe Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p289w.png)

I am looking to interpolate the column named, 'Horizon Azimuth', by a value of 1 like (0,1,2,3,....) and linearly interpolating the column, named, 'Horizon Height' accordingly.

I am not quite sure, how to do that. The dataframe interpolations mostly I saw is about NaN value filling.

Thanks,
Debayan

Answer (score 0):

Make the `Horizon Azimuth` column the index, then use [pd.DataFrame.reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html?highlight=reindex#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) to add the indices that you want. This will result in the `Horizon Height` column having NaNs values in the newly created rows. Then use [pandas.DataFrame.interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) to replace the NaNs with linearly interpolated values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Horizon Azimuth': [2,5,7,8], 'Horizon Height': [0,4,6,11]})

df = df.set_index('Horizon Azimuth')
new_index = range(2,9) # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
df = df.reindex(new_index)
df = df.interpolate(method='linear')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Horizon Azimuth  Horizon Height
0                2        0.000000
1                3        1.333333
2                4        2.666667
3                5        4.000000
4                6        5.000000
5                7        6.000000
6                8       11.000000
```

Hope this helps.